# Equivalent of a typedef in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, types, google-bigquery

When writing BigQuery functions, I keep reusing the same structure declarations, some of which are pretty long as they represent complex structures.

In the following example, a table with the fields `a` and `b` is defined, and a function `addsuffix` is defined that basically needs to receive and return a table row. To define the function, a STRUCT repeating the definition of these two fields needs to be specified explicitly *both* as an input and an output.

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  a STRING, b STRING                      -- a, b fields defined in schema
);

CREATE FUNCTION addsuffix(
  row STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING>          -- repeated in input parameter def
)
RETURNS STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING> AS (   -- repeated in output parameter def
  STRUCT(CONCAT(row.a, '_a_suffix') AS a, CONCAT(row.b, '_b_suffix') AS b)
);

SELECT addsuffix(r) AS withsuffix FROM mytable r;
```

This is very much redundant and doesn't allow for observing the DRY principle. Is there a way of defining a "typedef" that encapsulates a STRUCT definition once, so it can be reused multiple times without repetition? So the function would look something like the following:

```sql
TYPEDEF row_type AS STRUCT (a STRING, b STRING); -- defined once
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION addsuffix(row row_type)     -- reused in input def
RETURNS row_type AS (                            -- reused in output def
  STRUCT(CONCAT(row.a, '_a_suffix') AS a, CONCAT(row.b, '_b_suffix') AS b)
);
```

Assuming there is no such language feature - is there some equivalent pattern that can be used in order not to have to repeat the same structure definitions over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an easy fix, use `ANY TYPE` - function works even if you don't define the input variables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp.mytable (a STRING, b STRING);INSERT INTO temp.mytable (a,b) VALUES('aaa','bbb')
;

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION addsuffix(row ANY TYPE)
RETURNS STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING> AS (
  STRUCT(CONCAT(row.a, '_a_suffix') AS a, CONCAT(row.b, '_b_suffix') AS b)
);

SELECT addsuffix(r) AS withsuffix FROM temp.mytable r;
```

[image]

Then you can also skip the `RETURNS` part with SQL UDFs:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION addsuffix(row ANY TYPE) AS (
  STRUCT(CONCAT(row.a, '_a_suffix') AS a, CONCAT(row.b, '_b_suffix') AS b)
);

SELECT addsuffix(r) AS withsuffix FROM temp.mytable r;
```

End result: No `TYPEDEF`s needed anywhere!

Check out this post for some interesting UDFs:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83

Comment: Thanks! Does this have any practical downsides on the dev experience or on performance?
I'm asking because I assume some type-checking moves into the query execution flow whereas it previously ran first.

Comment: Also, still looking for another solution that would work with a JS UDF... Both of these shortcuts work only with an SQL UDF.